# Jquery currency Change with cookie function

Tags: jquery, cookies, geolocation, currency

I have a website , Hostingshine.com

I want a script to work but a normal one or else you can see this

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
    $('#usd').click(function(){
    $('.usd').show();
    $('.inr').hide();
    })

    $('#inr').click(function(){
    $('.inr').show();
    $('.usd').hide();
    })
          });
```

Using it with Jquery,

And the page goes like this

```
<ul id="currencychange"><li>
  <a id="usd">USD</a>&nbsp;<a id="inr">INR</a>
</li></ul>
```

and given the classes inr and usd to the place i want to show the desired currency 
but every time i change pages or refresh the pages it goes back to default i.e, usd.

Please help me with this, help me to get the cookie function or the geo function to work with this code ...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can use geoplugin library from here 
http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/javascript
and do something like following code:


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var currencyCode = geoplugin_currencyCode();
            $('#currencychange').children().children().each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('id') != currencyCode.toLowerCase()) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }


            });


        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="currencychange">
    <li>
        <a id="usd">USD</a>&nbsp;<a id="gbp">GBP</a>
    </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have You seen My Page? It is that many places there are USD value and i want to convert it all to Different Currency Value by javascript. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Do you want to convert USD to local currency ? For example if someone from India accesses the page say something is USD 10 the currency will change to RS 500 (asuming exchange rate for USD 10 equals RS 500 for that day)?

Comment: Yes... please have a look to atraxdesigns.com/test/index.html

Comment: The code I have posted will get you the local currency. Thats what you had in your original question. To get exchange rate use this  site to make an ajax call http://openexchangerates.org/documentation/#how-to-use and then using similar logic as I posted in the above code to update the values. Let me know if you need further help on it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full solution David: You will have to add references to geoplugin and money.js like I have done in the code below. 
I have also added comments after each line. If you dont understand any thing just ask.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--Add a reference to geoplugin -- we will use this to get geo/local settings -->
    <script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--Add a reference to money.js -- we will use this to convert our currency -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://josscrowcroft.github.com/money.js/money.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // get local currency code using geo plugin
            var localCurrencyCode = geoplugin_currencyCode();


            // make an ajax call to open exchange rates
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://openexchangerates.org/latest.json',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(json) {
                    // Rates are in `json.rates`
                    // Base currency (USD) is `json.base`

                    // set the returned values to money.js object
                    // we will use this later for currency conversion
                    fx.rates = json.rates;
                    fx.base = json.base;

                    // get exchange rate for local currency
                    var exchangeRate = json.rates[localCurrencyCode];

                    // get all elements on page that has a class of currency (you can use the same logic for selection or have your own)
                    $(".currency").each(function () {
                        // extract price eg if $10.00 get 10
                        var priceRaw = parseFloat($(this).html().replace('$',''));

                        // convert the price to local price
                        // we use money.js for this
                        var priceLocal = fx(priceRaw).from(fx.base).to(localCurrencyCode);


                        // finally we construct our price and inject it in the html
                        var finalPrice = localCurrencyCode +  priceLocal;
                        $(this).html(finalPrice) ;

                    });
                }
            });




        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="currencychange">
    <li>
        $10 = <a class="currency">$10</a><br>
        $20 = <a class="currency">$20</a><br>
        $30 = <a class="currency">$30</a><br>
    </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi David, please accept the answer as correct once you are happy. I spent an hour constructing a solution for your problem but you haven't given me any feed back.

Comment: I am sorry Brother..  but i was having a headache... Thanks for doing it for me. i tried to construct it but its giving me INR NaN in place of USD.

Comment: Brother. There is no need to make another script. If you can chat with me online i will make you understand better on what i want and what are the problems...

Comment: Hi David, email me at haroonxml@gmail.com with requirements and the issues you have.